# How to make make Xamarin on MacOS work with F# 64-bit?

Tags: macos, xamarin, f#, mono, 64-bit

I'm running Xamarin 6.3 on MacOS Sierra 10.12.4
It looks like when Xamarin is installed as-is from the .dmg downloaded from Xamarin site, only mono 32-bit version is installed.

I've been trying to follow [these](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/FSharpRProvider/mac-and-linux.html) instructions.

So far, mono64 is installed successfully on my machine, and on the Terminal Window, i can execute FSI in 64 bits
[image: FSI executed in a terminal]

However on Xamarin after switching my settings here[image: F# settings in Xamarin]

(fsharpi64 is a modified script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
EXEC="exec "

if test x"$1" = x--debug; then
   DEBUG=--debug
   shift
fi

if test x"$1" = x--gdb; then
   shift
   EXEC="gdb --eval-command=run --args "
fi

if test x"$1" = x--valgrind; then
  shift
  EXEC="valgrind $VALGRIND_OPTIONS"
fi

# Beware this line must match the regular expression " (\/.*)\/fsi\.exe" when fsi.exe is fsi.exe.
# That's because the FSharp MonoDevelop addin looks inside the text of this script to determine the installation
# location of the default FSharp install in order to find the FSharp compiler binaries (see
# fsharpbinding/MonoDevelop.FSharpBinding/Services/CompilerLocationUtils.fs). That's a pretty unfortunate
# way of finding those binaries. And really should be changed.
$EXEC /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/bin/mono64 $DEBUG $MONO_OPTIONS /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/fsharp/fsi.exe --exename:$(basename "$0") "$@"
```

)

I am still in 32 bits execution in Xamarin[image: FSI Xamarin is still 32bits]

The next unanswered question is how to COMPILE in 64 bits in Xamarin

Comment: `how to COMPILE`?... Are you talking about the FSI Pad?

Comment: well there are two distinct questions, but very similar
1- to make the F# interactive work in 64 bits in Xamarin
2- to compile F# projects in 64bits in Xamarin

Comment: The FSI Pad is defined via `fsharpbinding` and I  personally do not know of a way to spawn the `MonoDevelop.FSharpi.Service` as a 64bit process via MonoDevelop without mod'ing/building your own `fsharpbinding` Addin.... As far as compiling, when you build a F# project it will use the script (default or not) that you have defined in the prefs, you will still need to use `mono64` or supply the `--arch=64` when you actually run your compiled program.  FYI: All those F# Interactive options shown in your version, besides "Advance to Next Line", have been removed in the latest version.

Comment: To compile, you need to set the `PlatformTarget` in the .fsproj file to `<PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>`.

Comment: When you run the `AnyCPU` application from Xamarin studio, you need to ensure the project's Run configuration passes `--arch=64` to the Mono runtime.  This is done by editing the startup project's properties, going to Run > Configurations > Default > Advanced tab > click the ellipses next to "Mono Runtime Settings" > type `--arch=64` next to "Additional Options".